# iOS 8 sizeThatFits for UITextView text not returning correct height (AutoLayout)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitextview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to vertically center a UITextView using the appropriate height retrieved from `sizeThatFits`. There are a plethora of other answers that suggest this is the most appropriate way of calculating this.

(Note that I've tried it both with plain and attributed strings, and both exert the same behavior).

No matter what I try (even using attributed strings and setting the font size or line height to something bigger or smaller) it always only shows a certain truncated number of characters of text (in this case, 3 lines, and it's always exactly the same). What am I missing?

```
_textView.text = [_collectionDescription lowercaseString];
_textView.font = [UIFont fontLight:22];
_textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_constraintTextViewHeight.constant = ceilf([_textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)].height);

[_textView setNeedsDisplay];
[_textView updateConstraints];
```

Comment: Did you ever find a working answer? I'm having a crazy time getting sizeThatFits to work consistently regardless of the size of the text. Sometimes it leaves extra space at the bottom (not snug), and sometimes there's extra space but missing the last line of text. Anything?

Comment: See the answer below ;)

Comment: `sizeThatFits:` is deprecated in iOS 8

Comment: No, `sizeThatFits:` is not deprecated in `UIView` in iOS 8. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeThatFits:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As always with AutoLayout, you have to do:

```
[_textInfoView layoutIfNeeded];
```

(don't even need the `setNeedsDisplay` at all).

So, fully working:

```
_textView.text = [_collectionDescription lowercaseString];
_textView.font = [UIFont fontLight:22];
_textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_constraintTextViewHeight.constant = ceilf([_textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)].height);

[_textView layoutIfNeeded];
[_textView updateConstraints];
```

Comment: When using Auto Layout, just call `[_textView setNeedsUpdateConstraints]`, and layout will be triggered by updating constraints. When using manual layout, just call `[_textView setNeedsLayout]`, and have no need to call `layoutIfNeeded`, which will be done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `sizeThatFits:` method, you may use following method:
well you can try this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]};
// NSString class method: boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context is
// available only on ios7.0 sdk.
NSString *text = _textView.text;
CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:attributes
                                 context:nil];
_constraintTextViewHeight.constant = CGRectGetHeight(rect)
```

This method also considers line breaks in string `text`

Comment: NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: textView.font}; would be better :)

Comment: boundingRectWithSize is not returning accurate numbers also. So I would prefer to avoid that solution

Comment: I've had the same results with sizeThatFits: and boundingRectWithSize:.  They both return the wrong result.